# Magnify image in side-by-side images

Tags: graphics, tikz-styles

I need to magnify an image which I managed to do it using TikZ

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,black,magnification=5,size=1.5cm, connect spies}]
\node {\includegraphics[height=6.85cm, width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{figure}};
\spy on (0.15,0.1) in node [left] at (2,1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now I would like to put it side-by-side like this (for two general images)

```
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
    \subfloat[Subcaption 1]
    \includegraphics[height=6.85cm, width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{figure}
    \hspace{2mm}
    \subfloat[Subcaption2]
    \includegraphics[height=6.85cm, width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{figure}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

I tried to replace `\includegraphics` with the `tikzpicture` part but is not working like this

```
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
    \subfloat[Subcaption1]
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,black,magnification=5,size=1.5cm, connect spies}]
\node {\includegraphics[height=6.85cm, width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{figure1}};
\spy on (0.15,0.1) in node [left] at (2,1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{2mm}
    \subfloat[Subcaption2]
    \includegraphics[height=6.85cm, width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{figure2}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work if you add the missing curly brackets around the subfigures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h] \centering
\subfloat[Subcaption1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,black,magnification=5,size=1.5cm, connect spies}]
\node {\includegraphics[height=6.85cm, width=0.46\textwidth,
keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}};
\spy on (0.15,0.1) in node [left] at (2,1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\hspace{2mm}
\subfloat[Subcaption2]{
\includegraphics[height=6.85cm, width=0.46\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image}
}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]